What is the point of having field IsVisibleInApp on Knowledge__kav if it is always defaulted to true?
What is the point of having field IsVisibleInApp on Knowledge__kav if it is always defaulted to true?
Per documentation,
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_knowledge__kav.htm
IsVisibleInApp  
Type : boolean
Properties: Defaulted on create, Filter, Group, Sort
Description: Required. Indicates whether the article is visible in the Articles tab (true) or not (false).

Looks like this field is not available for editing, which means it is readonly and it is always defaulted to true, every article is visible in the Articles tab.
Then what is the point of having a field which always returns true?
If we try to create a record with this field value set to false, we will receive an error saying "Field is not writeable: Knowledge__kav.IsVisibleInApp"


I have opened the SF Support Case and I received the following response from SF Support team.
1. All Knowledge Articles always have value true in IsVisibleInApp field in Salesforce.
Yes

2. All Knowledge Articlces are always visible in the tab.
Yes

3. Since IsVisibleInApp field value is always true, this field presents no value for business implementation and is actually redundant and should be ignored or avoided.
Yes, currently this field has no relevance to implementation, and should be ignored as per existing product. We are saying so, because this field is not exposed editable to the customers. However, you always have an optio to post this idea on our below IdeaExchange page, stating your business requirement. This shall be included in the upcoming releases if product team considered your requirement valid.
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/

We are sincereley apologized for the inconvenience caused to you, and we would like to assure you that Salesforce support tried its best efforts to communicate directly with Product team to fetch the clear details to assist you with. Unfortunately, product is not supporting editing this field anyhow as per existing product feasibility.

